# Export Kinect Data RGB

Tags: kinect

I'm using kinect v1, ubuntu 14.04 and ROS Indigo. I would like to get kinect data each 1 second and export it to yaml file,because i will send it automatically to other PC to some processing.

Yaml file will help me to plot the pictures.

Thanks !

Comment: And the question being ?

Comment: How can i export these data from kinect ?